# Material ui react, ListItem The value provided 2 is out of range [0, 1]

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

i'm facing this issue with my navbar, and exactly with `ListItem` element, here is the error.

i have a custom theme config ( buyed theme), i think its coming from there, because as soon as i change `ListItem` with another element, the error disapear.

[image]

```
return (
    <Link href={href as string} passHref>
      <ListItem
        button
        disableGutters
        // activeClassName={
        //   isSubItem ? classes.isActiveListItemSub : classes.isActiveListItem
        // }
        className={clsx(
          classes.listItem,
          className,
          isLinkActive(router.pathname, href) ? classes.isActiveListItemSub : ""
        )}
        // isActive={(match, location) => {
        //   if (!match) {
        //     return false;
        //   }
        //   const { url } = match;
        //   const { pathname } = router;
        //   const isMatch = url === pathname;

        //   if (!isSubItem) {
        //     return url.length && pathname.includes(url);
        //   }

        //   return isMatch;
        // }}
        {...other}
      >
        <ListItemIcon
          style={{
            marginLeft: isSubItem ? "20px" : undefined,
          }}
          className={clsx(classes["listItemIcon"])}
        >
          {icon}
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText disableTypography primary={title} />

        {info && info}
      </ListItem>
    </Link>
```

This is the part of code triggering this error

Thanks you.

Comment: Please add your styling code to the question.

Comment: found it thanks mate, its was just adding two value for opacity resulting in more than 1 in opacity

Comment: I knew it has to do with the [alpha value](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/b3cd80d651db897fc336b13624be1237a0e31d80/packages/material-ui/src/styles/colorManipulator.js#L14), but I can't find the color setting code in your question.

Comment: yeah my bad, thanks anyway