# React, MUI: The value provided 1.7 is out of range [0, 1]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, create-react-app

I am working on a create-react-app project using Material-UI as a component library. On page reload, I get many similar errors from MUI.

[MUI: The value provided 1.7 is out of range [0, 1]. among others](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zspo.png)

The errors duplicate and they seem to be coming out of `colorManipulator.js` and `react_devtools_backend_compact.js` which I'm guessing are built in with the library.

I tried going over my code to see if I had the values 1.7 or 2 out of place in some of the component props.

However, I did not find 1.7 used, and 2 was used as a value in some of the components, but it was nothing out of the ordinary such as the elevation value in an MUI `Paper` component.

Also, I tried commenting out my css files and checking if it had something to do with the errors, but unfortunately that was also a bit of a dead end.

I have a lot of files in my app, so unfortunately I cannot pinpoint

Here is my package.json:

```
{
    "name": "homepage",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@auth0/auth0-react": "^2.1.0",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
        "@fontsource/roboto": "^4.5.8",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
        "@mui/material": "^5.13.5",
        "@mui/styled-engine-sc": "^5.11.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "axios": "^1.3.4",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "chart.js": "^4.0.0",
        "chroma-js": "2.4.2",
        "framer-motion": "^8.0.0",
        "jquery": "^3.6.3",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "prop-types": "15.8.1",
        "react": "^18.0.0",
        "react-bootstrap": "^2.7.2",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-query": "^3.39.3",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.8.1",
        "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
        "react-table": "^7.8.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
        "stylis": "4.0.13",
        "stylis-plugin-rtl": "2.1.1",
        "web-vitals": "2.1.4",
        "yup": "0.32.11"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
            "react-app",
            "react-app/jest"
        ]
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    }
}
```

After a bit of research, I could only find [1 post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67048680/material-ui-react-listitem-the-value-provided-2-is-out-of-range-0-1) that was similar to my issue but it did not help me.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Did you recently update MUI? Can you share your `package.json` file by editing the question?

Comment: @SimranSingh Edited, and did npm install once again, still same issue.

Comment: I solved it! I looked through my theme and played around with some of the opacity values in the `action:` part of the `palette`. I was having 0.7 and 1 registered at the same time and therefore it led the opacity to be 1.7 and probably some other values added up to 2.

Comment: Your error indicates MenuItem.js:78, you need to provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.